# PHP: how to print a variable value to screen if this is in a inner function

Tags: php

how can I print the content of a php variable on screen if the code is inside a function that is called without refreshing the page, but just to store same values in the database ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are there solutions here:

1. AJAX: Like Marc explained.
2. An iFrame: where you can have the form submission going through the iframe.
3. Comet: reverse-AJAX. Unlike AJAX, Comet doesn't require XMLHTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is the only solution. Javascript on the client calls the server, retrieves the value, and updates the necessary DOM object in the displayed page. Beyond doing a form submission (eg POST) or a page retrieval (eg. GET), there's no other way for PHP to affect what goes on in a page once it's been retrieved/displayed.

Comment: what about using a header function forwarding to the same website, and somehow passing the value ?

Comment: Header function? Forwarding? makes no sense. Maybe expand your question to detail exactly what you want.